# Xcode 7 can't find header files from search paths

Tags: ios, xcode, header-files

I am trying to compile bullet library for iOS and Xcode cannot locate the headers, despite entering the correct path to the library.

Please find two screenshots of the problem.

[image]

[image]

when right clicked on b3Contact4Data.h and revealed in finder it is located at the correct path:
/Users/pc12345/Projects/CodeFactory/Src/External/Bullet/src/Bullet3Collision/NarrowPhaseCollision/shared/b3Contact4Data.h

Also why would compile command doesn't mention the header search paths in the second screen shot?

Comment: Be sure to verify the physical path of the file. That will not necessarily match the project structure shown in Xcode.

Comment: thank you for your comment, when I right click any file in the project structure and choose show in finder  then I exactly go to the correct directory where the file really exists. The interesting question is why the header search path is not seen in the compile command in the second screenshot?

Comment: Problem seems to be related to the files with ".cl" extention. Inside these files no include files are found, while files with .cpp extention seems to find the same header files without problem . Any idea how to fix this? other than renaming all the .cl files?